# Dynamically change power bi embedded report based on user

Tags: powerbi, multilingual, powerbi-embedded

I have a user table. Each user has a language.

Is it possible to use this data to dynamically change the language based on the user in an embedded report?

Answer (score 3):

When you are embedding Power BI using the API, you can set the values of `language` and `formatLocale` properties in the [`localeSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/configure-report-settings#locale-settings) of the embed configuration, based on the language of the current user, e.g.:

```
let embedConfig = {
    ...
    settings: {
        localeSettings: {
            language: "en",
            formatLocale: "es"
        }
    }
};
```

At this moment, Power BI supports 44 different languages, which can be seen here: [Supported languages and countries/regions for Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/supported-languages-countries-regions).

For other types of embedding, it depends on the language settings of the browser and user's settings in Power BI.

I will recommend you to take a look at [Session 12: Building Multi-language Reports in Power BI](https://powerbidevcamp.powerappsportals.com/sessions/session12/).

Comment: Are we allowed to use this setting value as Parameter?

Comment: @Yiping Parameter of what? Power BI? No.

Comment: Right, must use measure with USERCULTURE()

Answer (score 0):

We ended up building a translations table in our data model that was much like a dictionary. We used the lookupvalue and in functions to do all of our dynamic translations based on user.